# File exists but getting warning of failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, copy, zip

```
<?php
$arch_filename = "myzipx.zip";
$dest_dir = "./dest";
if (!is_dir($dest_dir)) {
    if (!mkdir($dest_dir, 0755, true))
        die("failed to make directory $dest_dir\n");
}
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if (!$zip->open($arch_filename))
    die("failed to open $arch_filename");

for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; ++$i) {
    $path = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!preg_match('/(?:pdf)/i', $ext))
        continue;
    $dest_basename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    echo $path, PHP_EOL;

    copy("$path", "$dest_dir/{$dest_basename}");
}

$zip->close();
?>
```

A strange thing happend as this code worked only for 15 min now throwing warnings

> ( ! ) Warning: copy(myzipx/x/x.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\zip_ex\x\zip_img.php on line 21

But the file exists and echoing the correct file name. Don't understand what seems to be the problem .. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$path` is the name of a file inside the ZIP archive, not a file on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try with `copy()` was the right thing.
Unlike `ZipArchive::extractTo()` (which extract and create also the sub folders in the destination), the method `copy()` just copy/extract the specified file from the archive to the destination.

This example should work:

```php
$archive = "testarchive.zip";
$dest_dir = "./dest";
if (!is_dir($dest_dir)) {
    if (!mkdir($dest_dir, 0755, true)) die("failed to make directory $dest_dir\n");
}
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if (!$zip->open($archive)) die("failed to open $archive");

for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $file_name = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $file_info = pathinfo($file_name);
    $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (preg_match('/pdf/i', $file_ext)) {
        copy("zip://".$archive."#".$file_name, $dest_dir.'/'.$file_info['basename']);
    }
}                  
$zip->close();
```

Testarchiv structure:

```
xxxxx@xxxxxx:~/Documents$ tree testarchive
testarchive
└── test
    └── blubb
        └── test.pdf
```

The folder `testarchive` is then compressed to `testarchive.zip`.

After running code above:

```
xxxxx@xxxxxx:~/Documents$ tree dest
dest
└── test.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract from the zip archive.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; ++$i) {
    $path = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (preg_match('/pdf/i', $ext)) {
        $dest_basename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        echo $path, PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents("$dest/$dest_basename", $zip->getFromIndex($i))
    }
}
```

Comment: My Zip folder has sub_folders also.. I want to extract the files only not with the subfolders

Comment: `PATHINFO_BASENAME` just gets the filename without the folders.

Comment: Something is different . Its giving the output as x1.pdf (folder not a file), then inside the extracted zip folder with sub-folders which contains the files..

Comment: It should extract `x1.pdf` into `$dest_dir/x1.pdf`.

Comment: No it extracted x1.pdf as a folder which contains the whole zip folder with subfolders which contains the file

Comment: I changed `"$dest_dir/{$dest_basename}" ` to `"$dest_dir"` . But the whole folder is extracted, I just want the files without any folder .

Comment: I see the problem. The destination argument is treated as a directory, and then `$path` is appended to it to get the place to save to. It will have to be done by reading the archive file and writing to the desired location. Give me a sec.

Comment: Sure and Thank You